# How to do nothing in an SQL case statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I need to update a column conditionally and in some cases not update it at all. this is the best way i can figure to do that but it seems like it may be inefficient in the ELSE as it's still updating the column with the current value of the column. Is there a better way in which the ELSE can just "do nothing" at all.

```
UPDATE mytable
SET col1 = CASE WHEN (col1 = 20) THEN 10 ELSE col1 END
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply a `WHERE`:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET col1 = 10  
WHERE col1 = 20
```

However, if your update is more complex and you actually need multiple `CASE` you either have to bite the bullet and omit the `WHERE` or you have to add all columns in the `WHERE` which you want to update:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET col1 = CASE WHEN (col1 = 20) THEN 10 ELSE col1 END,
SET col2 = CASE WHEN (col2 = 40) THEN 20 ELSE col2 END,
SET col3 = CASE WHEN (col3 = 80) THEN 30 ELSE col3 END
WHERE col1 = 20 OR col2 = 40 OR col3 = 80
```

This might still "update" columns unnecessarily(to their old values) but not complete rows.

Comment: However, if the `UPDATE` is more complex, and needs to update other columns that are not restricted by this `WHERE` clause, his original method is the way to do it.

Comment: the update is more complex.  as @Barmar states.  i will need to do multiple updates in 1 statement. so each Case will need to do nothing on it's own.

Comment: @glutz: Then your sql is wrong and you should show a better sample. However, if it's more complex i would also use your approach whith `CASE`. Your question doesn't suggest this, though.